# Step-by-step instruction of best practice for using Facebook SignUp and Facebook Login in my iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I know, this might be a very naive question, but I'm having hard time imagining a complete picture of how Facebook SignUp and Facebook Login should be used in my application. I understand Facebook documentation, but it gives me scattered pieces which I can't figure out how to put together. I would appreciate any links for how-tos regarding this issue.

The problem I'm trying to solve, is simply to use Facebook SDK to register users in my application. But, what does this mean? Generally, if we take e-mail registration, this means getting e-mail address and a password, which will be used for later logins. For every login, my server will generate a session id, which will be used in API calls.

Now, I can obtain user's e-mail using Facebook SDK. But now what? What about the password? How should I generate a session id now on my server? Do I have to perform Facebook login call every time I start the app? Or should I send access token to my server and store it in users table and use it for generating session id? I don't need to perform Facebook Graph API calls in my app. All I need - is "single-click" signup/login functionality. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: As far as I know, any third-party sign-in API will detect if the user is logged into that system on your device, and will allow the remote (Facebook) server to issue an authentication token to you via an API. You thus do not need to handle credentials, since the third party handles this for you (and you should not want access to a user's Facebook credentials anyway).